# Foreach item in TableLayoutPanel row1

Tags: c#, winforms

At runtime I add some panels to tbl1 row and column 1 (`tbl1.Controls.Add(pnl,1,1)`). Now my question is: How can I loop into row 1 column 1 to select only 'pnl' items ?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do something like the following

```
foreach ( Control c in this.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls )
{
    Console.WriteLine(this.TableLayoutPanel1.GetRow(c));
}
```

look at this MSDN Link as well for [TableLayoutPanelClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx)